# How to implement H-infinity controller in STM32 platform?

Tags: control-theory, pid-control, matlab, optimal-control, robust-control

I used matlab to simulate some H infinity controllers, and I have some understanding of the related theory.  But I don't know how to implement H-infinite controller on STM32 platform using C/C++ code.

I have a relatively high performance STM32H7 series, and I am currently only good at using PIDs, so I have no idea how to write H-infinity related code on an STM32 controller. My goal is to control a DC brushed motor using an H infinity controller, to implement a (current loop) torque loop, and to get a fast step response (rise time less than 50us). Does anyone have any suggestions or examples to learn from? Or have any ideas?

Comment: Once the design process is complete, doesn't an H-infinity controller look like a normal controller? If so, consider rephrasing your question to something like "*How to implement a general transfer function*".

Comment: I means, How to implement it on stm32 platform. For example, Synthesising a H2/H-inf controller typically relies on solving some algebraic Riccati equations, I dont know how to do this on STM32 platform.

Comment: I never actually implemented such a controller outside of MATLAB/Simulink, I have no idea about this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need your *micro controller* to solve the Ricatti equations? I would have assumed that the *design* process is done on a PC (with Matlab) and only the *final implementation* would be translated to the micro controller. Have you looked what Matlab outputs when you ask it to design a controller ? It is simply a transfer function; right ? Once the controller is output by Matlab, would anyone be able to tell that it came out of the H-infinity design procedure? Please include the the controller equations in the question using [edit]. *Not* the Ricatti equations.